# Docker Cannot start service as already exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

Running `docker-compose up -d` I got the following error:

```
Starting cr-redis ... 
Starting cr-rabbitmq ... 
Starting cr-rabbitmq ... error

Starting cr-redis ... error

Starting cr-mysql ... error

ERROR: for cr-mysql  Cannot start service mysql: container "ff36...1116": already exists

ERROR: for rabbitmq  Cannot start service rabbitmq: container "3b6c...0aba": already exists

ERROR: for redis  Cannot start service redis: container "e84f...df91": already exists

ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: container "ff36...1116": already exists
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.


docker-compose ps   
     Name                    Command                State                                    Ports                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cr-mysql       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Exit 255                                                                       
cr-php-fpm     /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/php-f ...   Exit 255   9000/tcp                                                            
cr-rabbitmq    docker-entrypoint.sh rabbi ...   Exit 255                                                                       
cr-redis       docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Exit 255                                                                       
cr-webserver   nginx -g daemon off;             Exit 255   0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9003->9003/tcp
```

How can I start again the container without recreating it? I just don't want to lose the data in the DB.

--------------- UPDATE --------------------

```
$ docker-compose stop
$ docker-compose start
Starting redis     ... error
Starting rabbitmq  ... error
Starting mysql     ... error
Starting php-fpm   ... error
Starting webserver ... error

ERROR: for rabbitmq  Cannot start service rabbitmq: container "3b6c...0aba": already exists

ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: container "ff36...1116": already exists

ERROR: for redis  Cannot start service redis: container "e84f...f91": already exists
ERROR: No containers to start
```

Comment: Ok, I faced the same situation a couple of days ago and I had to remove (`docker-compose down`) and recreate the containers again. But this wasn't a problem for me because I didn't need to keep the data. I've noticed a few issues on github mentioning the *"container already exists"* problem and that it will be resolved in the `18.03` release.

Comment: Great point, I've Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de447b5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your case is probably related to a bug that will be fixed in the `18.03` release. Some workarounds are proposed here:

- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/211
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36145

---

> `docker-compose up` builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Since your `images` are built and the `containers` of your service have started, you can then use

- `docker-compose stop` and
- `docker-compose start`

to start/stop your service. This is different from `docker-compose down` which:

> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by `up`.

---

Regarding the danger of losing your data if a container is removed, read about *persistent storage* and how to use *volumes*.

Comment: I think is the bug due to the version I am.
Docker version 18.02.0-ce

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `docker-compose start` instead:

```
$ docker-compose start --help
Start existing containers.

Usage: start [SERVICE...]
```