# Docker-compose won't restart upon reboot

Tags: docker

Here's a piece of my composer file:

```
kodi:
    build: ./kodi-rpi
    image: kodi-rpi
    restart: always
```

No matter what I do, the container never restarts itself if I reboot the machine. In docker cli, if I run with the restart option it works: the container starts after reboot.

Also, when I reboot and try to do `docker-compose up` it complains that my old container already exists, making me manually delete it with with `docker rm` so then I can do `docker-compose up`.

Comment: There are some known issues about "container already exists" kind of problems. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49278089/1561148).

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute `docker-compose up --force-recreate` option if you don't want to execute `docker rm`.

If your container keeps in exited status, is possible also to use `--remove-orphans` options, but be careful that it'll remove all orphans, not only corresponding orphans containers which services are defined in your compose file.

Comment: but is there a solution to make it always restart automatically?

Answer (score 0):

What Docker version are u using?
I just tried it out with portainer:

```
version: '3'
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: "portainer"
    restart: always
    command: --no-analytics
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /srv/portainer/data:/data
```

I am using Docker Version 18.03.0-ce.
It seems like this is an Bug in your version.
You can try to upgrade Docker to the newest version.

Comment: indeed it looks like a bug. Gonna wait to see if mine reboots okay again and I'll accept this as answer