# PHP: Cannot create docker container

Tags: laravel, docker-compose

When I clone Laravel project from github and run command:

```
"docker-compose run --rm composer install"
```

After that I got this error:

```
Creating php ... error

ERROR: for php  Cannot create container for service php: Conflict.
The container name "/php" is already in use by container
"5d255feb437e580b70d683b18b4cfaadb64cc84d1a419f2fabbec451f15832ba".
You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

How can I solve this error?

Thank you.

Comment: does this help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278020/docker-cannot-start-service-as-already-exists

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already have an existing container under the name `php`. To verify this, you can list all containers (even the stopped ones) by running `docker ps -a` which would output something like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
5a6d2a808dda        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   22 hours ago        Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       nginx
```

Then if it's ok for you to remove the container named php, simply run `docker container rm <container_id>`, where `<container_id>` is the container id that you just got in the list.

So in your case, you would have to run:

```
docker container rm 5d255feb437e
```

If you have a lot of stopped containers due to multiple tests and you want to start "clean", you can also use `docker container prune` to remove all of them at once.

Edit:

As @bhucho mentioned, you can also rename the old php container instead or removing it. To do so, use the following command:

```
docker rename <old_container_name> <new_container_name>
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
docker rename php php_old
```

Comment: you can even use `rename` instead of `rm` to rename the container

Comment: Yes you're right @bhucho, I've completed the response with a rename example.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your issue then @ChamodiKulathunga Kulathunga. Thanks!